# Alarm service as background service

Tags: android, service, alarm

for my application I need to write a background service which prompt alarm according to the times in DB. I am using an Activity to start my service. Could any body help to autostart application instead of clicking of Application icon?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED). You can register broadcast receiver with this action to receive event when Android has just booted.

Comment: And in that `BroadcastReceiver` you should be registering alarms with `AlarmManager`, to wake up your code when it is time to "prompt alarm".